# Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This component does work:

```
export class Template extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div> component </div>
        );
    }
};
export default Template;
```

If i remove last row, it doesn't work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

I guess, I don't understand something in es6 syntax. Isn't it have to export without sign "default"?

Comment: you can write as


`export default class Template extends React.Component {`

Comment: I know. But how can I import component that was exported without "default"? It should be possible

Comment: @stkvtflw If I answered your question please accept it so other users can benefit too.

Answer (score 636, accepted):

Exporting without `default` means it's a "named export". You can have multiple named exports in a single file. So if you do this,

```
class Template {}
class AnotherTemplate {}

export { Template, AnotherTemplate }
```

then you have to import these exports using their exact names. So to use these components in another file you'd have to do,

```
import {Template, AnotherTemplate} from './components/templates'
```

Alternatively if you export as the `default` export like this,

```
export default class Template {}
```

Then in another file you import the default export without using the `{}`, like this,

```
import Template from './components/templates'
```

There can only be one default export per file. In React it's a convention to export one component from a file, and to export it is as the default export.

You're free to rename the default export as you import it,

```
import TheTemplate from './components/templates'
```

And you can import default and named exports at the same time,

```
import Template,{AnotherTemplate} from './components/templates'
```

Comment: OK.  But this seems like yet another seemingly arbitrary decision that I don't  see the rationale for but have to memorize.  Am I missing some good reason it is like this?  In many a project there will be dozens of React components.  Having each its own file, no matter how small seems, well, a bit anal.  It particular gets painful if many of them share clumps of helper functions. It makes for more lines of stuff to keep in sync which seems a bit counter-goodness.  What am I missing?

Comment: All stylistic decisions and conventions like this are somewhat arbitrary and down to personal preference.  You're right, sometimes it might make sense to group many components into one file with helpers, especially for small/simple projects. I guess one reason to have one component per file is testing ... when importing that file to test it, it can help if you're just importing the minimal amount of other code and sub-dependencies along with it. Another reason could be for simple diffs on small focussed files during code reviews etc.

Comment: Good answer. I have something to add to it:
Try to use imports statements like this:  
`import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';`  
instead of  
`import {RaisedButton} from 'material-ui';`  
This will make your build process faster and your build output smaller.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: @ShekharKumar Do you have a source for `import Binding from 'module/Binding'` being more efficient than `import {Binding} from 'module'`?

Comment: what about the case where you want to be able to both of these things: import colors from './colors' and import {red, green,yellow,blue} from './colors' ?  Do you have to define the vars twice? once as an object and then a second time an individually exported constants?

Comment: @DanielLefebvre check my last example, you can import named imports and the default import at the same time. e.g. `import colors, {red, green, blue} from './colors'`

Comment: How can one pass ```props``` through a named export? React does not seem to understand this syntax when passing props. I wanna export several styled components with their respective props along.

Comment: @Alioshr I think something else is going wrong in your case, there's no difference from React or Styled Components point of view in terms of default or named exports. Once those are imported, they are the same JavaScript object.

Comment: I am using styled components with SSR, in this case, namely, NextJs. I still very new to this framework. The problem was that I needed to workaround the SSR rendering with async code to manage to receive the props in a timely manner. Problem solved

Answer (score 16):

Add { } while importing and exporting: 
`export { ... };` |
`import { ... } from './Template';`

**export** → `import { ... } from './Template'`

**export default** → `import ... from './Template'`

---

Here is a working example:

```
// ExportExample.js
import React from "react";

function DefaultExport() {
  return "This is the default export";
}

function Export1() {
  return "Export without default 1";
}

function Export2() {
  return "Export without default 2";
}

export default DefaultExport;
export { Export1, Export2 };
```

---

```
// App.js
import React from "react";
import DefaultExport, { Export1, Export2 } from "./ExportExample";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <strong>
        <DefaultExport />
      </strong>
      <br />
      <Export1 />
      <br />
      <Export2 />
    </>
  );
}
```

⚡️Working sandbox to play around: https://codesandbox.io/s/export-import-example-react-jl839?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

```
    // imports
    // ex. importing a single named export
    import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";
// ex. importing multiple named exports
    import { MyComponent, MyComponent2 } from "./MyComponent";
// ex. giving a named import a different name by using "as":
    import { MyComponent2 as MyNewComponent } from "./MyComponent";
// exports from ./MyComponent.js file
    export const MyComponent = () => {}
    export const MyComponent2 = () => {}
    
    import * as MainComponents from "./MyComponent";
    // use MainComponents.MyComponent and MainComponents.MyComponent2
    //here
```

**EXPORTING OBJECT:**

```
class EmployeeService { }
export default new EmployeeService()

import EmployeeService from "../services/EmployeeService"; // default import
```

**EXPORTING ARRAY**

```
 export const arrExport = [
        ['first', 'First'],
        ['second', 'Second'],
        ['third', 'Third'],
      ]
    
    import {arrExport} from './Message' //named import
```

// if not react and javascript app then mention .js extension in the import statement.

You can export only one default component and in import can change the name without aliasing it(using **as**).

Comment: Here we only have examples of exporting functions. Can we see how to export objects or arrays?