# react-native module export type

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native, conventions, es6-module-loader

I love RN but one issue that is really annoying me is lack of conventions. I'm used to it a bit as a js developer. But using ES6 or not

`render() {`  vs. `render: function() {`

is one thing. What I really can't understand is when I saw the [WebView module export example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content) as

```
exports.examples = [
  {
    title: 'WebView',
    render(): ReactElement { return <WebViewExample />; }
  }
];
```

And sometimes I see

```
export default PDFView;
```

I'm used to

```
module.exports = WebViewExample
```

Returning an object breaks my code and forces me to think about what type I should expect from each component. I understand the value of returning an object but it seems like a bad thing to start introducing in the docs. End of rant. What is `default` is for?

Comment: It's frustrating for sure. But could please you clarify your question? It's not clear what you're asking. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default