# Error in implementing custom native module for react native Android

Tags: react-native

I am trying to develop native module in android for react native.
Exactly followed the link at 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

but it is giving me error

```
/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ToastAndroid2.default.show')
```

I have implemented ToastAndroid.js

```
'use strict';
/**
 * This exposes the native ToastAndroid module as a JS module. This has a
 * function 'show' which takes the following parameters:
 *
 * 1. String message: A string with the text to toast
 * 2. int duration: The duration of the toast. May be ToastAndroid.SHORT or
 *    ToastAndroid.LONG
 */
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.ToastAndroid;
```

and then in other Jsfiles tried to import using

```
import ToastAndroid from './ToastAndroid';
```

Answer (score 1):

change the name of Module "ToastAndroid" because ToastAndroid module is already in react-native package.

Comment: I think it should not matter because namespace is different for ToastAndroid (react-native) where as here it's importing from custom module.

Comment: @L.Learner, can you please share android side code?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing wrong. `module.exports` as the name implies exports your module to one of many exports that the file `ToastAndroid.js` can have. It's called a *named export*.

The correct import will therefore be `import {ToastAndroid} from './ToastAndroid';`

If you want to use `import ToastAndroid from './ToastAndroid';`

You should write `export default NativeModules.ToastAndroid;`

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default) for more information.