# RouteHandler: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: react-router

The use of RouteHanlder gives two errors:

```
VM2805 bundle.js:9597Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

The structure of my application.

```
src
-- components
-- -- App.jsx
-- -- LengthModule.jsx
-- index.jsx
-- routes.js
```

My routes.js file

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={require('./components/app.jsx')}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={require('./components/LengthModule.jsx')} />
    </Route>
)
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';    
ReactDOM.render(<div><App /></div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

export class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>
            <RouteHandler />            
        </div>;
    }
}
```

LengthModule.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';

export class LengthModule extends React.Component {        
    render () {
        return <div>"Hello World"</div>;
    }
}
```

Am I using RouteHandler correctly? What am I missing? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render () {
    return <div>
      <RouteHandler />            
    </div>;
   }
}
```

LengthModule.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';

export defaulf class LengthModule extends React.Component {        
   render () {
    return <div>"Hello World"</div>;
  }
}
```

[Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)

Answer (score 0):

Newer tutorials warn: [Be Careful About Deprecated Syntax](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/#article-header-id-15). This article specifically mentions "`<RouteHandler />` is Deprecated."