# I want export more than one 'Pure component'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making app with using React Native.
I noticed strange thing.

This code got me error unless I change last sentence to

`export default MyButton3;`

I want to export more than one pure components per file. I can do that if I don't use pure component declare.

But Why I can't do that with pure Components?

Thanks.

```
const MyButton3 = (props) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[props.style,{height:40, backgroundColor:Asset.color_skyblue, justifyContent:'center'}]} onPress={props.onPress}>
        <Text style={{color:'white', alignSelf:'center', fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

export MyButton3;
```

Comment: I guess this explain my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. Your question is more about the syntax on how to export multiple functions in one file. You have 2 syntax choices:

```
const a = 1
const b = 2
export { a, b }
```

or

```
export const a = 1
export const b = 1
```

Then to import to a file

```
import { a, b } from 'some directory'
```

Comment: Ah, you're right! Thanks. I will mark it as answer after 10 minutes. I have one more question. Where can I put 'props type' when I use 'export const MyButton...'?

Comment: `MyButton.propTypes = {}`

Comment: @BrightLee You're taking about typechecking, right? https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Ah......... I can still do that even after I removed 'export default MyButton' sentence. Thanks!