# exporting React component class with one name, importing it with another name, still working. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, es6-class

here is one file (`clock.js`) for my React app

```
class Clock extends Component { ...
...}
export default Clock;
```

here's another where I'm importing the Clock component

```
import Clock_1 from './clock/clock';
...
<Route exact path="/clock" component={Clock_1} />
```

as you can see, I exported it with name Clock and imported it with name Clock_1, still it is compiling and running successfully. Why?

`PS: Apologies beforehand if this question sounds lame/ too simple/ stupid. I'm a beginner.`

Comment: probably you should read more about `import/export`

Comment: you are using `default` export. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)

Comment: @kLabz thank u for replying. My question is in different context than the one you shared in this link. The link argues about the existence of 'exports default' whereas I am discussing the nature of 'imports/ exports' functionality.  Though some parts of the link's answer DOES intersect with my question's answer, it is not same scenario, hence **not** duplicate.

Comment: The question is different, but the answer is the same (named exported vs default export, default export not being bound to any name and thus allowing you to use them with whatever name you want).

Comment: Could be, coz I'm still reading about this topic, but since you already know, it could be the same answer. But ques are not same, are they? Sry if i sound rude arguing about this :D I just think if tomorrow a person has the same problem like mine, he won't search for a question like the one on the link, but something similar to what i posted here. Since when i searched for this problem, the link never came up in my search result, bcoz of which I had to post this question. **But** then again, I should have gone deep into the imports/exports docs & u did good pointing out that link.Thnx again :)

Comment: Yeah, I used the duplicate flag to provide the answer available there, not to sanction this question. It was more of a "the answer to this question is available there". That, and it was the first link in the "related" section in the right column :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[ES6 Feature]** First of all `default` keyword with `export` allows us to set Anonymous Name we want to set when we `import` it.

If you export it with

`export const Clock`,

then you have to import it strictly(ES6 way - using object destructuring syntax for named exports) with

`import { Clock } from './Clock`

or also can use `import * as Clocks from './Clock'` if you want to import all constants/variables(i.e. all named exports jammed into one object). This will make `Clocks` as an object with all exported variables/anything within it.

Like 
`Clocks = {
 Clock : Clock \\ import {Clock} from './Clock',
 ....
}`

Named exports are useful to export several values. During the import, it is mandatory to use the same name of the module as it was defined in source file.

But a default export can be imported with any name for example:

```
export default k = 12; // in file test.js

import m from './test' // note that we got the freedom to use import m instead of import k, because k was default export

console.log(m);        // will log 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use export default. Which means that you export only that class so the name is not that relevant.
Anyway, that's why TSLint(a set of rules) says that it's forbidden to use export default.

Answer (score 0):

its es6 feature, its just like giving an alias name or assigning one variable reference to another with some other name

behind the curtain it is like this when you import with some other name:

`Clock_1 = Clock`