# Failed to compile ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'UserProvider' is not exported from './model/UserContext'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm getting the following error, a would love it if someone could point me in the right direction :)

> Failed to compile ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'UserProvider'
>   is not exported from './model/UserContext'.

**UserContext.js**

```
const UserProvider = ({  children, history}) => { ... })
export default withRouter(UserProvider);
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/navBar';
import Login from './components/login';
import Session from './components/session';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard';
import './App.css';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import { UserProvider } from './model/UserContext'


function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <UserProvider>
      <Session />
       <NavBar />
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
         <Router>
         <Route path='/Login' component={Login}  />
         <Route path='/Dashboard' component={Dashboard}  />
         </Router>
       </Container>
      </UserProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting UserProvider as default. So in App.js just import like below(Without curly braces).

```
import UserProvider from './model/UserContext'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { UserProvider } from './model/UserContext'
```

You need to write like:

```
import UserProvider from './model/UserContext'
```

Comment: This same exact suggestion was provided a year ago. There’s no need to suggesting it again.